# Cannot Deploy Smart Conract to BSC TESTNET in Remix IDE

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, evm, bsc

I am trying to deploy a smart contract using Remix and the injected Metamask provider connected to the Binance Smart Chain Testnet (BSC Testnet). Everything was working fine yesterday, but today I want to deploy the latest version of the smart contract and I'm getting the following error message:

```
creation of WasteTransaction errored: Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{\"value\":{\"code\":-32603,\"data\":{\"message\":\"Internal Server Error\"}}}'","id":1970080652825218}
```

I have tried the following steps without success:

Checked my Metamask account balance and made sure I have enough balance on the BSC Testnet.
Increased the gas price and gas limit in the transaction.
Updated Remix and Metamask to the latest versions.
Can anyone provide any insights into the possible cause of this error and how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: The `Internal Server Error` message seems like an issue on the node.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is your problem, it's a problem with the BSC testing network.

Answer (score 0):

you need to adust gas fee manually and make it default for bnb testnet work.